# segment leaf (extract contour) from natural background

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have a leaf image such as the one below -

[image]

I want to segment the main visible leaf in this picture. The main leaf in my dataset can be distinguished using the fact that the background is blurred. I tried basic thresholding however I lose the parts inside the leaf that may not necessarily be green. (such as the yellow spots in this picture). May I know some methods I can try out to effectively segment this leaf? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try to extract contours plus remove ones from non green area. You will obtain contours free background which you could mask by filling connected components.